# PagedList.Mvc throws exception on MvcHtmlString

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pagination

I'm trying to use the great [PagedList.Mvc](https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList) paging library in Visual Studio 2015 RC but am getting this exception from my view:

> The type 'MvcHtmlString' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.   web.app.DNX 4.5.1

I've tried adding the `System.Web.Mvc` reference but it's not available under references.

Here's my view that throws the error:

```
@using PagedList.Mvc; //import this so we get our HTML Helper
@using PagedList; //import this so we can cast our list to IPagedList (only necessary because ViewBag is dynamic)
@using web.app.Models;

@model StaticPagedList<Entry>

@{
    if (Model.Count > 0)
    {
        @foreach (Entry entry in Model)
        {
            <h3>@entry.Title</h3>
            <h4>@entry.PublishDate</h4>
            <div>@Html.Raw(@entry.content.text)</div>
            <hr>
        }
        <!-- output a paging control that lets the user navigation to the previous page, next page, etc -->
        @Html.PagedListPager(@Model, page => Url.Action("~/Views/Shared/_RssFeedPartial", new { page }))
    }
    else
    {
        <p>There are no blog items to be displayed at this time.</p>

    }
}
```

Here's its controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? page)
{
    var pageIndex = (page ?? 1) - 1;
    var pageSize = 2;
    int totalPostCount;

    var feedItems = await RssManager.GetFeedItems("http://example.com/blogs/news", pageIndex, pageSize);
    totalPostCount = feedItems.Count;

    var postsAsIPagedList = new StaticPagedList<Entry>(feedItems, pageIndex+1, pageSize, totalPostCount);
    ViewBag.OnePageOfPosts = postsAsIPagedList;

    return View();
}
```

**Update 1**: One thing to note -- the parent page sends in the ViewBag list this way:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_RssFeedPartial", (IPagedList)ViewBag.OnePageOfPosts
```

**Update 2**: After making the changes suggested by both @Tommy and @Aegis, now getting these errors:

> 'RazorPreCompileModule' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments  web.app.DNX 4.5.1   ...\src\web.app\compiler\preprocess\RazorPreCompilation.cs  8
>
> 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddMvc' and no extension method 'AddMvc' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  web.app.DNX 4.5.1   ...\src\web.app\Startup.cs  69
>
> 'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseMvc' and no extension method 'UseMvc' accepting a first argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    web.app.DNX 4.5.1   ...\src\web.app\Startup.cs  113
>
> 'IHtmlHelper>' does not contain a definition for 'PagedListPager' and the best extension method overload 'HtmlHelper.PagedListPager(HtmlHelper, IPagedList, Func)' requires a receiver of type 'HtmlHelper'    web.app.DNX 4.5.1   ...\src\web.app\Views\Shared_RssFeedPartial.cshtml 23

Comment: Have you tried downloading the Microsoft ASP.NET MVC package through NuGet? I believe that is the easiest way to add the missing library.

Comment: Thanks, @Aegis. Which version?

Comment: If you're unsure of which version, I'd just download the latest one.

Comment: @Aegis: I'll get the pre-release one: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/6.0.0-beta4

Comment: I wouldn't get the pre-release unless you are running on ASP vNext.  Also, you probably shouldn't use any pre-release unless you are simply testing.  I believe the current, full, production MVC version is 5.2.3

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that you have the proper assembly redirects configured in your root web.config file. It appears that this assembly is looking for MVC version 4 *specifically*.  In order to add an assembly redirect, open your web.config file and add the following information (assuming using the latest production release of MVC):

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

This will cause any request for any version of the System.Web.Mvc assembly to be a call to the version you have installed.  If you do not have MVC installed, use Nuget to install the package and all related dependencies.

Note, you may already have this section in your web.config, if so, simply add or update the current System.Web.Mvc binding redirect.

Comment: Thanks, @Tommy. Now getting new errors. Please see update to question above.

Comment: It appears that my app won't run with anything but the pre-release version of ASP.NET MVC. Once I updated to that and removed the PageList.Mvc stuff, the app compiled. Is there a way to do the `web.config` mapping you have above to the `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 6.0.0-beta4` version? This is just for testing. Thanks.

Comment: @Alex - sure, just change the version from 5.2.3.0 to 6.0.0.0.  However, since Mvc 6 is written against vNext, I would wager that you might have some compatibility issues between this plugin and MVC 6

Answer (score 1):

Install a version of the ASP.NET MVC package through NuGet through the package manager or the GUI: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
```

Comment: Thanks, @Aegis. Just installed `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 6.0.0-beta4` but still getting error.

Comment: A similar issue was previously posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853442/the-type-system-web-ihtmlstring-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-referenc Seems they were missing a reference to System.Web. Have you tried adding that?