# Reference to type 'IHtmlString' claims it is defined in 'System.Web', but it could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I am trying to display some data from database into a grid and doing sorting & paging on that grid. Rather than creating sorting & paging manually, i found about WebGrid or GridView (old framework). I need similar grid that I can use for new .NET 6+

I am using Visual Studio 2022 to make an ASP.NET Core web app using .NET 6.

I searched on google but it said to either use older version of .NET Framework or use ASP.NET Core MVC or adding a reference inside the system file.

I don't want to use an older version of .NET or Visual Studio. I am not using MVC. I only have a `program.cs` file in my project, not `system`.

[ref link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.helpers.webgrid?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2)

```
@using System.Web.Helpers;
@{
    var webGrid = new WebGrid(Model.ShapesList);
    @webGrid.GetHtml()
}
```

i downloaded following nugets:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlSe
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tool
```

> Error: Reference to type 'IHtmlString' claims it is defined in 'System.Web', but it could not be found

Comment: There's something wrong with your project file, like referencing an asp.net 2 package, or something corrupt in your working folder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference to type 'IHtmlString' claims it is defined in 'System.Web', but it could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69510418/)

Comment: no, sorry. `.NET Framework` version is like 10 years old version. I am trying to keep .net 6+

Comment: Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages is for .net 4.5 not for .net 6. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40912473/can-system-web-be-used-with-asp-net-core-with-full-framework), I don't think you can use `System.Web` in asp.net core, You need to find a method with similar functionality in .Net Core.

Comment: You are confusing the (really old) ASP.NET Web Pages framework with ASP.NET Core Razor Pages. You cannot use the WebGrid helper in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: awh ok that answer my question. I didnt knew WebGrid is for old framework only. Is there a WebGrid alternative for `.net 6+` or no?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I just need a grid for .net 6+ so I dont have to manually create html table and track all sorting & pagging

Comment: There is nothing built into .NET 6 for that. You'll need to look for a third party solution.

Comment: sound good. that answer my question. Ill just build my own